# Les canettes de bière laissées au sol ou sur le sol

Tags: grammaire

Les canettes de bière laissées `au sol ou sur le sol` ?

Moi j'ai entendu quelqu'un dire `au sol` alors que pour moi il faudrait dire `sur le sol` car on parle de l'emplacement des bières.

Quelle est la règle grammaticale employée?

Comment: Intuitivement, on peut différencier *au* et *sur* par les emplois usuels de *laisser* : « Laisser *à l*’abandon → laisser *au* sol » — « déposer *sur* → laisser *sur* le sol ». Le choix peut refléter l’intention du geste qui a amené cette situation ; on retrouve des canettes jetées n’importe où, ou déposées dans un endroit qui permettra un ramassage facile sans gêner le passage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de règle grammaticale en ce qui concerne le choix des prépositions qui accompagnent un verbe; c'est une affaire de sémantique et d'usage. Dans le cas de "laisser" la sémantique veut que lorsque l'emplacement où la chose est laissée est de la sorte d'un récipient, cela pris dans un sens très large, la préposition soit "dans": laissé *dans* la casserole, laissé *dans* le bateau (mais aussi possible dans le cas présent "laissé *sur* le bateau);  l'usage veux que l'on dise "laissé **sur** le champ de bataille" dans le contexte de la guerre et non "laissé dans le champ", qui est le seul usage correct dans le contexte de l'agriculture.
En effet, il semble que l'on ne dise pas "laissé **au** sol"; en réalité cela se dit mais c'est utilisé bien moins fréquemment, ce que montre cet [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=laiss%C3%A9+au+sol%2Claiss%C3%A9+sur+le+sol&year_start=1800&corpus=19&smoothing=3&year_end=2008&direct_url=t1%3B%2Claiss%C3%A9%20au%20sol%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Claiss%C3%A9%20sur%20le%20sol%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Claiss%C3%A9%20au%20sol%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Claiss%C3%A9%20sur%20le%20sol%3B%2Cc0).

[image]